# Non-root jupyter notebook startup

Tags: anaconda, jupyter-notebook, sudo

I recently got a new Macbook Pro (Sierra 10.12.3) and wanted to install anaconda. I downloaded the graphical installer from the conda website and ran it; I mistakenly selected the option to install in root (ie not just for a local user). The installation went fine and python ran without a hitch. However, when running `jupyter notebook` I was told "Permission denied". `sudo jupyter notebook` worked.

Previously, I had been running an up-to-date conda and jupyter notebook on my previous laptop with Yosemite, and I had never had to `sudo` to run the notebook. As far as I've been told, letting programs (even trustworthy ones) run with root access should be avoided at all costs, so I wanted to try to fix this.

I used anaconda-clean and then removed the conda directory, and re-installed it for the local user (so now it sits in `~/anaconda/` and not `//anaconda/`). All `conda` commands now work without `sudo` *except* the jupyter notebook, which *still* requires `sudo jupyter notebook` or else it throws the same "Permission denied" error.

How do I solve this and enable the jupyter notebook to start up without root access? I do not know if this is a related issue, but the notebook starts up in Safari despite my default system browser being set to Chrome. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Most likely, your Jupyter cache directory is still owned by root. Try `chown`ing the `~/.jupyter` folder to your user

Comment: @darthbith the `~/.jupyter` directory is already owned by me. There is an `~/.ipython` directory that was owned by root. `chown`ing that recursively still didn't help. The `anaconda-clean` utility explicitly removes these config files when run though?

Answer (score 1):

Got it working; the key is in the ownership of the `~/Library/Jupyter` folder. As mentioned in the comments, the `anaconda-clean` utility deletes all the config files in the home/root folder, and then the removal of anaconda involves "simply" deleting the `//anaconda` or `~/anaconda` folders depending on which install was done.

However, it appears that the Jupyter Notebook creates the `~/Library/Jupyter` folder in the home directory, which I obviously missed! Recursive `chown` does the trick.

Incidentally, this also solves the browser problem, and the notebook starts up in Chrome as expected. I suspect this may have had something to do with `sudo jupyter notebook` starting up its own browser as root.

Comment: Glad you got it fixed! Indeed, the browser thing was probably that the default browser is set for you, not for the root user. "Jupyter Notebook creates its own folder in the home directory," can you be more specific about the name of this directory and help out future visitors?

Comment: Cool, edited to reflect. It's the one in `~/Library`

Comment: Awesome, would +1 again if I could!